# SQL Server Set variable if exists else insert into table

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, exists

I'm looking for a more efficient way of completing this task. I need to set a variable equal to an ID if it exists, and if not insert it and then set the variable to the inserted identity. I can accomplish this by doing the following:

```
@VariableName --sent through to stored procedure

DECLARE @VariableID [int]

IF EXISTS(SELECT VariableID FROM VariableTable WHERE VariableName = @VariableName)
    SET @VariableID = (SELECT VariableID FROM VariableTable WHERE VariableName = @VariableName)
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO VariableTable(VariableName) VALUES(@VariableName)
    SET @VariableID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

However it seems inefficient to run the same query twice (check if exists and if it does set the variable)

Just looking for suggestions on a better way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try :

```
DECLARE @VariableID [int]
SELECT @VariableID=VariableID FROM VariableTable WHERE VariableName = @VariableName

IF @VariableID IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO VariableTable(VariableName) VALUES(@VariableName)
    SET @VariableID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO VariableTable (VariableID )
 SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
FROM VariableTable
WHERE not exists
(
 SELECT VariableID FROM VariableTable WHERE VariableName = @VariableName
)
```

Then if you need the id you would have to set the variable the @@IDentity. I think this is most efficient as you aren't making a third query, but just just getting the last ID inserted.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this snippet and it executes correctly:

```
DECLARE @VariableID [int]
SET @VariableID=(SELECT VariableID FROM VariableTable WHERE VariableName = @VariableName)
IF @VariableID IS NULL
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO VariableTable(VariableName) VALUES(@VariableName)
  SET @VariableID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a lite modification to @Mithrandir answer. You can use `TOP 1` that help you to speed up the result when you are not comparing against unique field. e.g.

```
DECLARE @EXISTS AS BIT
SET @EXISTS = 0
SELECT TOP 1 @EXISTS = 1 FROM MyTable WHERE MyYear = @Year
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this amusing exception. Remember there's no BEGIN and END, so the next statement after the IF should be conditional. Now ask yourself why the first variable exists:

```
declare @check binary
declare @predeclared varchar(100)
select @check = 0

if @check = 1
   declare @conditionaldeclare nvarchar(4000)
   select @conditionaldeclare = 'conditionaldeclare'
   print @conditionaldeclare


if @check = 1
   select @predeclared = 'predeclared'
   print @predeclared
```